# Pretty URL - mod_rewrite question

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to setup a simple mod_rewrite for formatting "pretty URLs".  All I need is for something like:

http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/logs?page=12 to tranlate to http://www.example.com/logs/12

How would my .htaccess rule look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/logs/(\d+)$ /dir1/dir2/logs?page=$1
```