# How to remove query string using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

My URL: `example.com/epathasala/**schooldetails.php**?name=st-matthews-school`
example.com/epathasala/**collegedetails.php**?name=gtn-arts-college

Expected URL: 
`example.com/epathasala/**schooldetails**/st-matthews-school`
example.com/epathasala/**collegedetails**/gtn-arts-college

So I want to remove ?name= from the URL, Kindly Help me.

In that url query string only removed. In my case before query string also there is change.

Example Schooldetails is not static, it will change to collegedetails or events or university and so on

Comment: Did you try existing answers such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/9310224/3749523 ? Did it help you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty URL - mod\_rewrite question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654859/pretty-url-mod-rewrite-question)

Comment: Yes I have tried but its not working in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^epathasala/schooldetails/(.*)$ /epathasala/schooldetails.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: RamRaider Thanks, , But schooldetails is not permanent, its a dynamic value it may change to collegedetails.php or events.php or university.php and so on